# Чем библиотека react лучше нативного JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Чем библиотека react лучше нативного JavaScript? Есть ли смысл ее переходить на нее? Или это модное движение, как с jQuery в свое время? Какие плюсы от использования React?

Comment: модное движение

Comment: Как и предназначение любой другой библиотеки или фреймворка - облегчить работу с конкретными задачами, в случае реакта, **построение UI**

Comment: Ну так jQuery в свое время тоже был определённо лучше нативного js